# SharePoint 2010 - Modified Calender View

Tags: list, calendar, list-view

I want to filter the Calender in my SharePoint 2010. All Items with a Enddate older than 7 days must be hidden.
I found no way to modified the Calender View to filter the elements because the field "Enddate" is not in list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's anything like 2007, you need to do some Tomfoolery to make it work.

Create a calculated column called EndDateFilter and make it simply =[End Date].  Then filter the calendar view by EndDateFilter is less than or equal to [Today]+7.